# Symfony FormRenderer Error with CreateView

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try to create a Form with Symfony but get the Error:

Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock(): Argument #1 ($view) must be of type Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given

**Controller.php**

```
    public function set(Request $req)
    {
        $gericht = new Gericht();

        $form = $this->createForm(GerichtType::class, $gericht);

        // $em->persist($gericht);
        // $em->flush();

        return $this->render("gericht/set.html.twig", [
            "setForm" => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

**set.hmtl.twig**

```
{% block body %}

<div> 

    {{form("setForm")}}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to erase the quotation marks:

```
{{form(setForm)}}
```